# Returning Class<T> From a Method

Tags: java

I have two classes that extend a common base class. The base class has code that, for one concrete subclass, needs to know the `Class` of the other concrete subclass. So, given `Foo` and `Bar` extending `Base`, an instance of `Foo` needs to know `Bar.class`, and an instance of `Bar` needs to know `Foo.class`.

And, silly me, I'm trying to Do the Right Thing and use Java generics to ensure that the subclasses return a valid Java class object, one that extends the base class.

So, I tried this:

```
class Base {
  abstract protected <T extends Base> Class<T> getOtherClass();
}
```

The compiler seems reasonably happy with that construction. The problem comes in the implementations.

First, I tried:

```
class Foo extends Base {
  @Override
  protected <T extends Base> Class<T> getOtherClass() {
    return Bar.class;
  }
}
```

(where `Bar` also extends `Base`)

That complains that I have a type mismatch in the return value, and it requires a cast.

Then, I tried:

```
class Foo extends Base {
  @Override
  protected Class<Bar> getOtherClass() {
    return Bar.class;
  }
}
```

Now the compiler complains about needing a cast at `Class<Bar>`.

Then I tried:

```
class Foo extends Base {
  @Override
  protected Class<Base> getOtherClass() {
    return Bar.class;
  }
}
```

Now I get *both* complaints: needing a cast in the `Class<Base>` *and* in the return value.

Is there a way of expressing this that avoids any casts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base> {
  abstract Class<T> getOtherClass();
}
class Foo extends Base<Bar> {
   @Override Class<Bar> getOtherClass() { return Bar.class; }
}
```

...or...

```
abstract class Base {
   abstract Class<? extends Base> getOtherClass();
}
class Foo extends Base {
   @Override Class<Bar> getOtherClass() { return Bar.class; }
}
```

Comment: The second one is more what I was fishing for -- I'll accept this in a few minutes. Out of curiosity, do you know why `?` works and `T` (as I used it in the question) does not? Thanks!

Comment: When you write `<T extends Base> Class<T> getOtherClass()`, you are telling the compiler that a caller of your method can write `Class<WhateverSubclassOfBaseIWantNotNecessarilyBar> clazz = myFoo.getOtherClass()`.  You're saying that the _caller_ can choose a subtype of `Base`.  That's not what your method implementation says.  `? extends Bar` means that the _implementation_ chooses a subtype and the caller doesn't know what it is.  (That said, I think if you choose option 2, you'll find yourself down the line wishing you'd chosen Option 1 when you find yourself forced into awkward casts.)

Comment: Ah! OK, that makes sense. Thanks again! And with respect to Option 1, for this particular situation, I feel reasonably confident that Option 2 will work. This is for a seriously trivial example app for testing an Android O behavior change. I'm not actually using the `Class` myself -- I'm just passing it along to Android (explicit `Intent` constructor). Every now and then, I try pushing the boundaries of my understanding of the finer points of generics. :-)